# Connecting Led in Series with Parallel Switches

Tags: led, resistors, switches, wiring, breadboard

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

I created a diagram for a circuit that i am trying to implement. I have attached my circuit diagram and have been trying to implement it but still have not got it to work. I've checked all the wiring and they are all connected correctly and I am getting a Voltage source. Does anybody have any ideas? Am I missing something? Because when I press the switch, the LED is supposed to light up, but is not.(Not pictured: But I also tried adding a a connection to ground at the end of the first switch as well but that didn't do anything either.)

Comment: I noticed the LED is backwards in the schematic, is that a mistake in the schematic?

Comment: Other than that the schematic looks fine. Which way around is the LED on the breadboard? How come the switches aren't square to the breadboard? And are you aware the breadboard doesn't connect the 5 holes on the left half with the 5 holes on the right half?

Comment: @immibis Yes sorry I forgot to include that in my description. I also grounded the holes on the right half and also I accidentally flipped the LED in the schematic, apologies. Will update with pictures shortly.
Edit: I've updated my circuit with the addition of grounding my circuit for the 5 holes on the right half.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at this: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard/anatomy-of-a-breadboard - I don't think the switches are wired as you have drawn them but I can's see the connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LED is connected to nowhere.

On these breadboard, there is no connection on the central line. your orange cable connected on the other side to your 0V is actually not touching the LED pin.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was missing. Will upload a picture shortly of the complete circuit. Apologies if my circuit is very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have not connected the blue (Ground) busses together, so the terminal of the LED that should be connected to ground is not connected to anything.

The vertical busses running the length of the breadboard are probably not connected together, unless you make that connection yourself (and on some breadboards, those vertical busses have a break in the middle - you have to place a jumper over that break to make the buss run the full length of the board).

Also, as a comment mentions, the horizontal groups of five holes are not connected across the center "ditch".